# projects are created with errors in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using android studio and when i try to create a new project i found that the manifest file always contains `android:name=".MainActivity"` highlighted
with red as well as `AppCompatActivity`, `onCreate` and `setContentView` in the following code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how solve it

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

**style**:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">//cant  
resolve symbol Theme+cant resolve symbol AppCompat

</style>
```

Comment: It can also be that your computer isn't that fast and after creating the new project it took some time for the first gradle sync (build). Before that initial build, android studio doesn't recordnize your dependencies. Because the main activity is exntending AppCompat which is missing in this moment, the main activity himself is broken, which ends up in second error in the manifest. Try gradle sync and all should be fine

Comment: Try to rebuild the project.

Comment: @Rami i didi but the problem persists

Comment: Instead of AppCompatActivity try Activity

Comment: Maybe you can push you project to gihub.I will try to complie  when I'm free.

Comment: isnt there any other way instead of github..i am not familiar with it..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you need to upgrade Android Studio. Please go to 
-Tools/Android/SDK Manager, 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' (at the bottom) and install what it has pre-selected.

Sometimes when you have errors it will pop up in the top right of Android Studio presenting you with a 'Fix' button as well, try re-starting Android Studio and looking out for this option.

If the above suggestions don't work let me know and I'll look further into it.

EDIT: You have not included the support library dependency. This is why Android Studio cannot find AppCompat etc. Please go to your app level build.gradle file and include this line under 'dependencies' and re-sync your project (as it will ask you to do).

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: my sdk is upto date..and i invalidated and restarted Android studio..but i checked the theme file and it has errors as well...maybe fixing this errors can help..would u please tell me how the erros in the style file posted above can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try sync project with build.gradle.

[image]

Do you set right sdk path.

Comment: i tried it but still i have the same errors..please have a look at the style.xml posted above

Comment: yes the path is correct..i have this problem when i create a new projects only

Comment: Plz show me you sdkManager.Or you can just use copy old project's build.gradle

Comment: old project's gradle is the same

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the right versions for these lines. You are possibly using an older version of Build Tools or AppCompat library in your IDE. Maybe Android Studio is not updating the versions in your manifest file when you create a new project.

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"<--- This line


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'<--- This line
```

After installing the updated version of both of these lines, sync project.